# Embed a page into home page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using SharePoint Online and want to embed an existing SharePoint page into SharePoint home page(within a web part).

Is it feasible in SharePoint online?

Answer (score 0):

For displaying pages you can use

1. Page Viewer Webpart
2. Content Editor Webpart and use and IFrame
3. Use Script Editor Webpart to load the page using JavaScript

All the above will work only if you have the Page residing in the same site collection.

If it is not then we will receive following error

> Refused to display 'https://sitecollection/page.aspx' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.